# Nested comboboxes in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, combobox

I'm looking for a way of nesting comboboxes in my GUI application (or to be more precise, I'm looking for a way to have an item displaying similar visual and functionnal properties as nested comboboxes).

Looking first at all the functions provided by the combobox class, it seems comboboxes nesting it's not supported by Qt.

I therefore thought that another solution would be to create a "menu" item outside the menu bar. If I understand correctly this phrase from the offical [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-mainwindows-menus-example.html), it seems to be feasiable :

> A menu widget can be either a pull-down menu in a menu bar or a **standalone context** menu

Not sure though was is meant by the "context" word.

However, there is no such (menu) widget in Qt designer and I haven't found any good examples about how to do it on the internet (and can't get a menu not associated with a menu bar to be displayed on the windows), explaining why I'm currently doubting whether it's feasible or not with a menu item.

I would greaty appreciate if you could provide some code sample along your response.

**EDIT :**

To clarify my first post, I'm trying to do something similar to this app :[image: Space Mous entreprise app]

It's the application that comes along the 3D connexion mouse whose usage is to parametrize each button.

As you can see, there are several sub-menu items. By clicking on the arrow next to a textbox, you open a sub-menu containing itself folders that contains themselves paramaters.

Comment: _"Not sure though was is meant by the "context" word."_ Right mouse click context popup menu at any widget.

Comment: Combo box nesting... My mind can't fathom it.  The best way would probably be to create a second combo box on the GUI populated with your desired values after the user selects a value from the first combo box.  Unless you aren't looking for a combo box but instead more of a multi tier drop down menu.  Combo boxes right out can't be nested.

Comment: This looks like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Why do you think you need nested combo-boxes? What is the real problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I knew my question would be considered like a XY problem, that's why I tried adding some clarifications by adding this sentence "or to be more precise, I'm looking for a way to have an item displaying similar visual and functionnal properties as nested comboboxes)" but apparently, it didn't help. Anyway, I edited my picture to give an example of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @GuiliuG. I don't see anything that could be described as a "nested combo-box" in that image. The central item looks like a scroll-view containing a line-edit and a tree-view.

Comment: I've never said that there actually was a nested combobox in the example I showed, I just said it has a similar behaviour as nested comboboxes. Nested comboboxes being just after all a list of sub-items appearing when an item of a first "main" list has been hovered or clicked over.Yeah, I'm using a tree-view now but I honnestly thought there was an easier solution for what I was looking for. Thanks anyway.